# Is this a spectral decomposition/embedding/isometry?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Given a symmetric p.s.d matrix G, we know that a gram matrix/inner-product representation, X exists where $G=X^TX$ and $X=U\lambda^{1/2}$ via the eigen decomposition of $G$.

Now if I take the same matrix $G$ and find a matrix $V$ that minimizes $\sum_{i,j}G_{i,j}\langle v_i.,v_j.\rangle$ w.r.t $V$ where $V^T$ is constrained to be have $V^TDV=I$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix to avoid the trivial zero matrix solution while minimizing this. Also, lets assume that $V$ is non-singular. Given that all entries are real, then:

Basic questions:

q1) Is $V$ obtained via an isometric(inner-product) preserving transformation?

q2) Is $V$ a spectral decomposition?

q3) How is $V$ different from $X$?

q4) Any examples of where such $V$ can be useful?

q5) Is this some sort of an 'Embedding' from a metric spaces/topology point of view where some relations in the p.s.d matrix $G$ are preserved, via inner-products? i.e, if $G_{ij}$ is large, the minimization makes sure that the inner product $\langle v_i,v_j \rangle$ is smaller in comparison to smaller $G_{ij}'s$ where the inner-product can be larger.

You may assume positive semi-definiteness of $G$, if these questions make more sense in that case.

Advanced question:

Now if I said $v_i$ is instead the result of a vector-valued function $f_i(.)$ in a Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space (RKHS) where $\sum_{i,j}G_{i,j}\langle v_i.,v_j.\rangle$ is minimized again under orthonormal constraints on $V$ and when the inner-product is the RKHS Norm, what is special or useful about this transformation? You may also assume that we use a regularizer under the RKHS norm on $f's$ as well, if you were worried about some sort of lack of smoothening or trivial solutions. Any where that this is applied? What are its properties from  a functional analysis or linear algebraic or spectral analysis or isometric transformations or Hilbert space point of view? What is happening here !? is what am looking for and the mentioned subjects are the only areas that i reasonably can attempt to understand or have at least studied till now.

Comment: @julien We minimize the sum $\sum_{ij}G_{i,j}\langle v_{i\cdot}, v_{j\cdot}\rangle$ w.r.t $V$ and all entities lie in a Real, space. Also, if $G$ is assumed to be p.s.d, then the question of $X$ having an imaginary part doesn't arise, while I also constraint the $V$ to be real as well. All entries are real.

Comment: What are $v_i.$ and $v_j.$? Columns of $V$? Also, what is $\langle v_i., v_j. \rangle$? It looks like a scalar (inner) product.

Comment: @julien ok, it's the row $i$ of $V$ and is a vector, inner-product. I should have put $V_{i\cdot}$. Also, they are orthonormal because I mention the orthonormality on columns of $V^T$

Comment: @julien, Vedran Sego, Would it be reasonable to say instead that $VDV=I$ is the constraint, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix? My reasoning for the orthonormality was to bring some structure to the problem and to avoid the trivial zero solution for minimizing. I will change it if it sounds reasonable, while u dont see an issue in the definition with this update.

Comment: The sum in your original constraint is just a trace of $G$. Your $VDV = I$ boils down to $V^2 = D^{-1}$ or, equivalently, $D = V^2$, which brings us to $D = D^{-1}$, so $D = I$. You should first sort out what do you want.

Comment: @VedranŠego Also, the constraint on $V$ is $V^TDV=I$ not $VDV=I$. Instead of minimizing the Frobenius norm $||G-X^TX||$ over $X$, I have put in the sum of products of entries in $G$ with the corresponding inner products, which made me think of this question.

Comment: @julien The matrix $V$ has entries $v_{ik}$ and $v_{i\cdot} = (v_{i1},\dots,v_{in})^t$ and $\langle v_{i\cdot},v_{j\cdot}\rangle$ *is* the inner product. The matrix $V$ is not orthogonal, the rows are orthogonal but there's a weight matrix $D$ (probably the question was edited in the meantime).

Comment: @Martin,julien That's right. On the whole the point is to prevent the zero matrix solution for $V$. The $D$ can be the Identity as well or be more structured like the degree matrix of a graph where $D_{ii}$ is the sum of the corresponding column or row entries in $V$. But again, the main point was to prevent the zero solution.

Comment: If $D$ is diagonal, $I = V^T D V = V^T \sqrt{D}^T \sqrt{D} V = (\sqrt{D}V)^T (\sqrt{D}V)$, so $\sqrt{D}V$ is orthogonal. Since $v_k.$ are rows of $V$, this means that $\langle v_i., v_j. \rangle = \delta_{ij} / \sqrt{d_{ii}d_{jj}} = \delta_{ij} / d_{ii}$ ($d_{ij}$ are elements of $D$). It is important to decide what you want. "To prevent a zero solution" can mean "nonzero matrix" or "nonsingular matrix" or a bunch of other things. It's your call what's the actual problem here. Or I'm just not getting it, in which case I apologize for the intrusion.

Comment: @VedranŠego Oops..I meant to prevent "zero matrix", i.e to have a solution which is a nonzero matrix.

Comment: So, in the end, any nonzero $V$ is ok, even if it's singular?

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Comment: I have no idea at the moment how to handle this, but update your question, so someone else may solve it.

Comment: @VedranŠego I would say nonzero matrix and non singular, because there is a mention of spectral decomposition.

Comment: So, nonsingular. I've just noticed somethin. Let us denote $S(V) := \sum_{i,j}G_{i,j}\langle v_i.,v_j.\rangle$. Notice that $S(xV) = x^2 S(V)$ for any real number $x$. Let us assume that some nonsingular $V_0$ minimizes your sum. If $S(V_0) < 0$, then $S(xV_0) < S(V_0)$ for any $x > 1$. If $S(V_0) > 0$, then $S(xV_0) < S(V_0)$ for any $0 < x < 1$. In both cases, $xV_0$ remains nonsingular. So, nonsingularity is still not enough of a condition, sorry.

Comment: And, by the way, q1) it's obviously not isometry (i.e., orthogonal matrix); q2) makes no sense ($V$ is a matrix, not a decomposition); q4) why do you ask this if you have no idea where the solution is useful?!